# OPEN GRAPH meta tag DESCRIPTION not working in Linkedin share.Is there any way to show description in Linkedin share?

Tags: linkedin-api, share-open-graph

I am using the following Linkedin API for sharing from my application.
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=XX&title=XXXX&source=XXXXX. I am using open graph meta tags for binding the informations 'title', 'URL', and 'description'. But the description is not working with Linkedin. It is working fine with Facebook share.

Answer (score 0):

***Step 1 - Use the Right URL Format***

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

***Step 2 - Set Title, Description, Image using `og:` Tags***..

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

***Step 3 - Check Your Code***

Take the URL you are sharing (i.e., `example.com`, not `linkedin.com?share=example.com`), and input it into the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  You will be told everything that goes into determining how your webpage is shared on LinkedIn.